# A blank space appears after inserting an image in an HTML table

Tags: html, css, frontend

***When I inserted an image into the table data, there is a lot of white space to the right. Can you tell me why that exists?***

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Lorem, ipsum.</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        
       
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><img src="./profile.jpg" alt="rashmi-profile" width="20%"/></td>
                <td> 
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque, in.
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Please see below the output I want to remove the extra space after the image in the table data
[image]

Comment: try removing the width=20%

Comment: My image became huge when I did that bro

Comment: set a pixel value not a percentage one

Comment: Oh my god!! thank you so much, bro. It worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use from e.g `em` instead `%`:

```css
table,td {
  border: solid;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="https://s4.uupload.ir/files/7560b48482bfae5c-02b97ffc647f-3822363654_tji3.jpg" alt="rashmi-profile" width="100em" /></td>
    <td>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque, in.
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Because when you use `20%`, the width of `td` is considered 5 times the image.